# Book about a man with a special sword who helps a king and his daughter/s

Tags: story-identification, novel

In my younger days, there was a book I liked to read and the following are the faint details I remember about it.

1. I believe on the cover was a sword with smoke coming from the hilt; it's a faint memory, but quite sure that's the cover.
2. A man had telepathic communication with the sword and I think the sword's ability was to cover the area in black smoke or to render a person unconscious when touched (quite sure it was the smoke screen).
3. They helped a king and his daughter (or two daughters) overcome some obstacles and, towards the end of it, one of the princesses wanted to join the man and the sword on their journey.

I don't remember the title, but only the cover of the book. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1298628205i/399370.jpg - Smoking sword book cover

Comment: Vaguely matches *Warbreaker* except for the cover

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: cant remember the exact year i think 2015-2018 roughly...and the image would be of the sword by itself i think...its a real vague memory but one of the coolest books i read. imagine a sword against a black background with greyish blue smoke coming from the hilt towards the top of the book...i wish i can remember more

Comment: Update it might be warbreaker im going to use kindle credit and check it out thanks guys

Comment: Yep its the one i see

Comment: If anyone posts a correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 3):

So as per comments, this actually is *Warbreaker* by Brandon Sanderson.

- A telepathic talking sword that emits black smoke is the clearest element and matches Nightblood, Vasher's sentient abomination that gets used less like a sword and more like a dark grenade
- A king and his two daughters is a less clear match as the king only shows up for a prologue, but the book does start with a king of Idris choosing not to send his favored older daughter to be married as part of a surrender/treaty.  Siri is sent instead to be married, with Vivenna following her in an attempt to retrieve her and claim the role she was trained for, and the two are major point-of-view characters for the entire novel.
- Vivenna ends up joining Vasher in his travels at the end of the book.